# Dart Factories and several main functions

Tags: dart

I'm currently developing a website with dart replacing JavaScript. I want to have some code hidden for the average user, and some other code visible for users logged in. My idea was to have (at least) two dart files both with `main()` functions, one visible and one hidden to the average user. Now I have a class with a factory returning a cached instance. However this instance is not cached from file to file. How do I get the same instance in two different dart files?

**EDIT: Code example**

File `file1.dart`

```
import "some_lib.dart";

main(){
    var a = new A("string1");
    print(a.string);
}
```

File `file2.dart`

```
import "some_lib.dart";

main(){
    var a = new A("string2");
    print(a.string);
}
```

File `some_lib.dart`

```
library some_lib;

class A{
    String string;
    static A _cached;

    factory A(String s){
        if(_cached == null){
            _cached = new A._internal(s);
        }
        return _cached;
    }

    A._internal(this.string);

}
```

File `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/dart" src="file1.dart"></script>
        <script type="application/dart" src="file2.dart"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>THIS IS DARTA</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect this to print

```
string1
string1
```

in the console, but I get

```
string1
string2
```

Comment: If the class containing the factory constructor is imported (inside a library) then the instance should be cached. Can you give more details? Maybe an example?

Comment: I would expect that too, but that is not what I get. Please let me know if you get something different.

Comment: Please list the exact commands you are executing. If you are running these programs in your browser, please paste all the HTML files that contain the `<script>` tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two independent programs can not influence each other (except through IO operations like files and sockets).

From what I can see you are executing the VM twice with two different programs. Their libraries will be completely independent. Imagine that one important library with global state (like the lazy factory constructor you mention) is stored in a systems directory. If the library wasn't duplicated for every program, completely independent programs would interfere with each other.

Another way to look at it: the VM creates a new (implicit) isolate for each program. Programs have their own copies and memory. Even inside the same program you can only communicate between two isolates with message passing (where every message is serialized and deserialized). Two isolates would have different cached factory constructors, too.

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation about this? I would really like to fully understand this area.

Comment: I get that. But this is different from the behaviour of JavaScript, where you can declare a function in one file and use it in another. This behaviour must be documented somewhere?

Comment: Okay I found this: [link](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/embedding-in-html/#a-single-script-tag) .